# Find $\sup\{f(x)|x\in [\frac{r-1}{n}, \frac{r}{n}]\cap Q^c\}$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Find $$\sup\{f(x)|x\in [\frac{r-1}{n}, \frac{r}{n}]\cap Q^c\}$$ and 
$$\sup\{f(x)|x\in [\frac{r-1}{n}, \frac{r}{n}]\cap Q\}$$

where $     f(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  x^2,~~~ x\in Q\cap[0,1]\\
                  x^3, ~~~x\in Q^c\cap[0,1]
                \end{array}
              \right.
  $ such that $P_n=\{0, 1/n, 2/n,  \dots n/n\}$ is a partition of $[0,1]$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I am unable to solve this. I want to find sup in each of the subintervals. Please give me an idea to find the sup.

**Personal input**: 
$x^2>x^3$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and hence in each of the subintervals $[\frac{r-1}{n}, \frac{r}{n}]$, $r=1,2,3,...,n$. 
 So $$\sup\{f(x)|x\in [\frac{r-1}{n}, \frac{r}{n}]\cap Q\}$$ would be $\frac{r^2}{n^2}$ as $f(x)=x^2$ is monotone increasing on $[\frac{r-1}{n}, \frac{r}{n}]\cap Q$.

Correct? What about other one?

Comment: Where does $P_n$ enter your question?

Comment: @MichaelLee Actually I want to solve a problem on Riemann integration and $P_n$ is a paprtition on $[0,1]$. I need sup and inf for checking whether f is integrable on [0,1]. I stuck to find the $sup\{f(x)/x\in [\frac{r-1}{r}, \frac{r}{n}]\cap Q^c\} $. Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Every $$\frac{r-1}r$$ should read $$\frac{r-1}n$$

Comment: @Did Right. Thank you. I have edited.  Please give me a solution of this.

Comment: Sure -- as soon as you add some personal input.

Comment: @Did I put my personal input. Please check and suggest.

Comment: Right, correct in the Q-case. Now, simply copy this to solve the not-Q-case...

Comment: @did need your help. I suspect that denseness property may be needed here but unable to write in proper way.

Answer (score 1):

So $x\rightarrow x^{3}$ is increasing on $[0,1]$, so we target the $(r/n)^{3}$ if possible. For each $x\in[(r-1)/n,r/n]\cap{\bf{Q}}^{c}$, we have $f(x)=x^{3}\leq(r/n)^{3}$, so $\sup\{\cdots{\bf{Q}}^{c}\}\leq(r/n)^{3}$. And we can choose $(p_{n})\subseteq{\bf{Q}}^{c}$ such that $p_{n}\in[(r-1)/n,r/n]$ and that $p_{n}\rightarrow r/n$. For a small $\epsilon>0$, choose an $n$ such that $(r/n)^{3}-\epsilon<p_{n}^{3}$, this shows that $(r/n)^{3}\leq\sup\{\cdots{\bf{Q}}^{c}\}$ and hence $\sup\{\cdots{\bf{Q}}^{c}\}=(r/n)^{3}$.

Comment: Why downvote? Is it not correct?

Comment: @user1942348 "Is it not correct?" Can't you tell?

Comment: @user284331 f(x) is $x^2$ or $x^3$, you have taken $x\to x^3$, any other thing want to mean? please answer

Comment: For $x\in[(r-1)/n,r/n]\cap{\bf{Q}}^{c}$, then $f(x)=x^{3}$, so $\sup\{f(x): x\in[(r-1)/n,r/n]\cap{\bf{Q}}^{c}\}=\sup\{x^{3}: x\in[(r-1)/n,r/n]\cap{\bf{Q}}^{c}\}$, so I am dealing only for $x^{3}$.